# How to make this type of layout using grid layout in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Multiple grid layouts in one screen

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just a `ListView` with `GridViews` inside, and don't forget the `shrinkWrap` true for the `GridViews`

```
  class MultipleGridView extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Title 1"),
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("index: $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
            Text("Title 2"),
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("index: $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
            Text("Title 3"),
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("index: $index"),
                );
              },
            ),
            Text("Title 4"),
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("index: $index"),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are reusing some code again and again and takes up some memory. Why don't we generate that lines of codes dynamically? and yeah, i am new in flutter.

```dart
Text("Title 1"),
           GridView.builder(
             physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
             shrinkWrap: true,
             gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
               crossAxisCount: 5,
               crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
               mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
             ),
             itemCount: 10,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return Container(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 child: Text("index: $index"),
               );
             },
           ),
```