# How to make border inside GridView

Tags: flutter

So what I'm trying to achieve is GridView like this apps I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me?

[image: GridView]

Comment: well you can use the grids parameter on the gridview `gridDelegate` and set the `crossAxisCount` to 3, and style the children, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845295/how-to-make-this-type-of-layout-using-grid-layout-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work perfectly, check it out.

This is the grid view

```
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          children: List.generate(
            20,
            (index) => _gridTile('Sarapan'),
          ),
        ),
```

This is the grid tile widget

```
Widget _gridTile(String name) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black54,
          width: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The code above produces the output below:
[image: Output]

Comment: any clue how to do style like pictures above?

Comment: You can tweak my code above to obtain that by adding the images and icons. I hope this helps.